# How do you obtain a gitlab CI job's correlation ID(s)?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to debug an issue with a server/service used by gitlab CI runners. In looking at the associated service's logging, the entries are [tagged with a *correlation ID* (the `"correlation_id"` field in their structured log](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/tracing_correlation_id.html)).

The runner apparently uses `curl` (or, perhaps, `libcurl`) and should thus be [able to provide info on the correlation ID](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/tracing_correlation_id.html#getting-the-correlation-id-from-curl). However, it's not obvious how to cajole the local curl[-like] client into providing the `x-request-id` header field (i.e., the correlation ID).

Looking at [the libcurl docs](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-env.html), there is a variable that looked promising (`CURL_TRACE`) -- setting that to `1` in the job didn't seem to produce any different/additional output (i.e., nothing containing the headers) in the job log, even when used with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`, `GIT_TRACE=1`, and `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1`.

Is there some other way to coax the runner to provide correlation IDs?

Comment: Are you using a self hosted runner? If you are you can supply a debug argument when starting the runner and watch all the output that’s logged and it might help?

Comment: @quizguy the runners are on corporate infrastructure (that I have limited admin access to).

Comment: In that case I’d try running: gitlab-runner stop; followed by gitlab runner  —debug run; and it will give you a whole  bunch of runner information. Im not sure entirely if it will contain what your after but would be a nice place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Correlation IDs are only found in the GitLab logs or in HTTP *responses* from GitLab. This also only applies to GitLab's services and is an internal mechanic. You do not need to do anything to get correlation IDs to appear in logs or responses. If your jobs or other code *you* write use `curl` to communicate with GitLab, you do not (cannot) provide the correlation ID yourself.

For example, when the gitlab runner makes a POST request to the jobs API on the coordinator (the gitlab server) you will a log similar to the following in GitLab's logs:

```
{"content_type":"","correlation_id":"01234ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU","duration_ms":1,"host":"gitlab.example.com","level":"info","method":"POST","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.1","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:0","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","route":"^/api/v4/jobs/request\\z","status":204,"system":"http","time":"2022-06-30T00:17:40Z","ttfb_ms":1,"uri":"/api/v4/jobs/request","user_agent":"gitlab-runner 15.1.1 (15-1-stable; go1.17.7; linux/amd64)","written_bytes":0}
```

You will only be to see GitLab's logs if you are self-hosting GitLab and have access to its logs (typically a system administrator would be able to see these by looking for them on disk). If you are using gitlab.com you do not have access to these logs.

As a client, you can see the correlation ID in the response headers in the HTTP **responses** from GitLab.  Using `curl` as an example, you can add the `--verbose` flag to see the response headers.

Here we'll `grep` for the `x-request-id` to make it easier to see.

```
$ curl --verbose https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/278964 2> >(grep x-request-id)
< x-request-id: 01G6S0168KKRNVNM5610DRXVPW
```

> Looking at the libcurl docs, there is a variable that looked promising (CURL_TRACE) -- setting that to 1 in the job didn't seem to produce any different/additional output

Setting variables like `CURL_TRACE` in your job will not impact the interactions between the runner and GitLab (1) because the runner environment/configuration is isolated from the jobs it runs and (2) the runner does not use curl; GitLab runner [communicates to GitLab using golang http libraries](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/blob/main/network/gitlab.go#L10-11).

> Is there some other way to coax the runner to provide correlation IDs?

TL;DR no. The runner does not log HTTP response headers from requests it makes to GitLab. This is not possible unless you modify the source code of the runner to log response headers and recompile the runner yourself from your modified source code.

Comment: `GIT_TRACE_CURL=1` seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @jhfrontz I don't think so?  I tried replicating that on gitlab.com, but it doesn't cause the job to show any correlation ID... unless I'm misunderstanding the question somehow.

Comment: I think maybe my use of "provide" is causing confusion.  I understand that the server is generating the info.  I was trying to get the *client* to display the information that it had received.

Comment: I see. Do you mean for a client that runs _inside_ your job (for example if you run `curl` in your job script)? Or do you mean the _runner_ itself as a client (for example, when the runner sends requests to GitLab like for job updates)? In the former case, that is clearly possible. In the latter case, I don't think so.

Comment: I think the latter case, though I must confess to being quite ignorant about the inner workings of the runner. It seems to be associated with `00:05:42.796603 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git-remote-http origin http://gitlab-ci-token:...`

Comment: Interesting. In any case, I'm glad you found something that works @jhfrontz. Though I [tried to reproduce it here](https://gitlab.com/sytech/stackoverflow/how-do-you-obtain-a-gitlab-ci-jobs-correlation-ids/-/jobs/2659479233). I do see a bunch of headers from the git operation, but I didn't get any correlation ID. If I had to guess, I think you may be seeing output from your job making curl requests, not necessarily the _runner itself_.

Comment: It's before the actual job (meaning the `script` part, right?) has started its work.  It's in the setup part that the runner performs on every job.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more searching and trial-and-error, I found that setting `GIT_TRACE_CURL=1` (as a CI/CD variable) causes the runner to display all of the response headers.  The correlation ID is in the `X-Request-Id` field:

```
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< Vary: Accept
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="GitLab"
< X-Accel-Buffering: no
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
< X-Request-Id: 01G6RYV1S0CP53PM5YFG00YGB4
< X-Runtime: 0.089969
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2022 00:05:42 GMT
< Content-Length: 26
```